# mail (gnu mailutils) 3.4 not able to send an attachment

Tags: server, email, postfix, mail

We upgraded from Ubuntu 14.04 to Ubuntu 18.04 and now we are not able to send emails with attachments.

On Ubuntu 14.04, we have mailutils 2.2 and we used to use the following command

```
mail -s "subject" -a "file.tar.gz" email@domain.com < /dev/null
```

This worked without any problems.

But on Ubuntu 18.04 and mailutils 3.4-1, it does not send as an attachment.

Researching showed me that mailutils now requires `-A` or `--attachment`

[Invoking Mail (GNU Mailutils Manual)](https://mailutils.org/manual/html_node/Invoking-Mail.html)

These are some of the commands I've tried.

```
mail -s 'Test Email' -A file.tar.gz email@domain.com < /dev/null
mail -s 'Test Email' -attach=file.tar.gz  email@domain.com < /dev/null
```

However when I try to use -A or --attachment, it gives me the following errors respectively:

```
mail: invalid option -- 'A'" and "mail: invalid option -- '-'
```

I was able to successfully send attachments using "mutt" but would like to see if I can resolve this issue so I can send attachments using "mail".